# How can I add data scaffolding to an existing ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I've added in the Dynamic Data stuff to our existing website, and gotten that working as far as adding a DynamicDataManager to a page and setting a GridView to use it.  However I think I'd like to get the full scaffolding functionality up and running so I don't have to write all the layouts for all the tables.  Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

I've added code to Application_start() to register the data context and set up the route.  I've tried with both "{table}/ListDetails.aspx" and "{table}/{action}.aspx" versions but I only get an HTTP 404 error.  I also have ScaffoldAllTables set to true.

Am I missing a step or two here?

Here is my application start code:

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        }


public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            MetaModel model = new MetaModel();


            model.RegisterContext(typeof(ESLinqDataContext), new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });


            routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/ListDetails.aspx")
            {
                Action = PageAction.List,
                ViewName = "ListDetails",
                Model = model
            });

            routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/ListDetails.aspx")
            {
                Action = PageAction.Details,
                ViewName = "ListDetails",
                Model = model
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

to the httmodules section of my web.config.

Comment: OK. Glad to see you found the solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this in your global.asax

```
model.RegisterContext(typeof(AdventureWorksLT_DataModel.AdventureWorksLT_DataEntities), 
new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.aspx has a step by step walkthrough..see if you missed any.

Comment: In the above article, please check the first comment about deleting the app_code folder and putting the dbml file in the root to gain access to DataContext.

Comment: The dbml file is in a dll file... do I have to do something special for that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your Application_start() code? And which version of IIS are you using?

A good explanation of adding Dynamic Data to an existing website can be found on Scott Hanselman's website: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Comment: Version 5.1 of IIS, but I'm running it through visual studio... 

will post the app_start in a sec

Comment: I don't think it's an IIS problem... I set up a quick Dynamic Data Web Application and it's working fine through Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

see:

[Walkthrough: Adding Dynamic Data to an Existing Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668188.aspx)

[Scott Hunter : How to add Dynamic Data to an Existing Web Site](http://blogs.msdn.com/scothu/archive/2008/06/23/how-to-add-dynamic-data-to-an-existing-web-site.aspx)

All the requirement s are there for getting DD working in a existing website.